# Nic Gallagher's CSS pseudo element parallax effect to vertical

Tags: css

**Please no jQuery / plugin solutions**

Attempting to convert Nicolas Gallagher's parallax demo from horizontal to vertical. The first two links are the original horizontal demo; the 2nd jsFiddle is my attempt to convert it to vertical

[Here is Nic's original demo - for reference only](http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/demo/backgrounds.html)

[jsFiddle of Nic's original horizontal demo - for reference only](http://jsfiddle.net/3u8tP/1/)

[jsFiddle attempting to convert demo to vertical - FIXING THIS ONE](http://jsfiddle.net/ygshc/1/)

After a few hours' tinkering, I am out of ideas. At this point, all I have managed is to align the images to the right side of the screen and extend the view.

I have not been successful getting the vertical parallax to work. *As you can see, I am trying to do all of this using css pseudo elements - but I am open to a bit of javascript/jQuery if that is the best way to make it work.*

```
#silverback {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 1800px;
  padding: 120px 0px 50px;
  background: #d3ff99 url(http://i59.tinypic.com/4q60dh.png) 100% -10px repeat-y;
}
#silverback:before,
#silverback:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
#silverback:before {
  content: '';
  vertical-align:text-top;
  background: transparent url(http://i58.tinypic.com/4toj7o.png) 100% 300px repeat-y;
}
#silverback:after {
  content: '';
  vertical-align:text-bottom;
  background: transparent url(http://i60.tinypic.com/103s9j7.png) 100% 70px repeat-y;
}
```

I am pretty sure that the answer has something to do with the `background` property for each pseudo/element. In the original horizontal demo, the `-10 / 70 / 300` is what created the parallax effect.

So I've tried (see 2nd jsFiddle above):

```
-10px / 70px / 300px

-10% / 70% / 300%
```

Setting each to `100% / repeat-y` is what aligned everything nicely on the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Height cannot be fixed. In the original example the width is automatic, and that's one of the factors that produces that effect.

So you have to add `height: 100%;` to `#silverback`.

http://jsfiddle.net/AcG96/

---

> *I am open to a bit of javascript/jQuery if that is the best way to
>   make it work.*

Same CSS as in my fiddle, but also add:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
  document.getElementById('silverback').style.paddingTop = document.body.scrollTop + 'px';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AcG96/1/

You should start with a fixed position in your CSS, then switch to absolute in javascript, that way your background stays fixed and covers the window if javascript is disabled.

Comment: Thanks that worked in jsFiddle, but can't make it work in my real-world test. If page is larger than the small jsFiddle panel, it does not `repeat-y`, and there is no parallax effect. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without javascript. Note that this doesn't work in the original demo either. Scrolling =/= resizing window